# HTTPS Sniffer for .NET ?

Tags: http, web, https, sniffer

Problem : I would like to record all the http and https request made from any browser installed in my computer thru a windows application.

So, I would like to know is there any http and https sniffer (including commercial tools) libraries which I can use in my .NET applications ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need this for investigation, and don't really need to build it into your app, you can just use Fiddler as a stand-alone proxy.  You'd need to use a cert, in order to decrypt the traffic. In essence, you'd be doing a man-in-the-middle exploit.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiddler_(software)
http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: Thanks for your help ! Its perfectly suits my need but I have to distribute this with the application and I have requested Telerik for license pricing and I was shocked with pricing.. They need 50 k for 2 year license.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking to do is set up an HTTP Proxy.

I would suggest checking out [FiddlerCore](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/fiddlercore).